# Setting up a user registration in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to set up a user registration application in Java. Here's my current code (yields an error)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Registration {

    private static ArrayList<String> userlist = new ArrayList<String>();


    public static void requestRegistration(String username, String password, String f_name, String l_name, String email)
    {
        userlist.add(username, password, f_name, l_name, email);
    }
```

This code does not run because you cannot add multiple arguments to an array. I'm thinking my array list should be a String array instead of just String. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You should create a "user" class, which has each piece of information (name, password etc.) as a property, and make an ArrayList of that class instead.

Your idea of an ArrayList of string arrays could work; but having a type to describe your data makes things much easier and is a better practice.

For example, suppose you were reading someone else's code. I think you'll agree that:

```
Authenticate(u[0], u[1]);
```

Is less readable than:

```
Authenticate(u.username, u.password);
```

Over time, if you wish to add more data to a user, it's easier to deal with new properties than with an ever growing array of strings.